# An integral with the $\Gamma$ function: $\int_{c- i\infty}^{c+i\infty} u^{s}\:\Gamma(\beta +s-1) \:ds$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I previously posted a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078664/residue-theorem-for-gamma-function) and I have solved many of the problems from the answers given with explanations. This time however I am at this point of integration where:

$$\int_{c\ -\ i\infty}^{c\ +\ i\infty}
\left(x^{-1}\sigma\right)^{s}\Gamma\left(\,{\beta +s-1}\,\right)\,{\rm d}s$$

where $\beta$, $\sigma$ and $x$ are real numbers.

I know that Cauchy's residue theorem is applicable for the evaluation but I cant figure out how can the simplification be made.

Comment: Is $\beta$ a real number?

Comment: @OlivierOloa yes, $\beta$ is a real number. i'll edit my question with this line in

Comment: OK, I give you an answer within some minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just use the previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078664/residue-theorem-for-gamma-function/1078754#1078754) given to the question in reference. If you perform the change of variable $s \to t$, with
$$
\beta+s-1=\frac{t}{2}, \quad ds=\frac12 dt,
$$ your initial integral is now equal to
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\left(x^{-1}\sigma\right)^{1-\beta}}{2} \int_{2(c+\beta-1)\ -\ i\infty}^{2(c+\beta-1)\ +\ i\infty}
\left(\left(x^{-1}\sigma\right)^{1/2}\right)^{t}\Gamma\left(\frac t2\right)\,{\rm d}t \\\\&=\frac{\left(x^{-1}\sigma\right)^{1-\beta}}{2} \int_{c'\ -\ i\infty}^{c'\ +\ i\infty}
u^{t}\:\Gamma\left(\frac t2\right)\,{\rm d}t\\\\
&=\frac{\left(x^{-1}\sigma\right)^{1-\beta}}{2} 4\pi i\cdot e^{-\dfrac{1}{u^2}}\\\\
&=2\pi i\:\left(x^{-1}\sigma\right)^{1-\beta} \cdot e^{-\dfrac{x}{\sigma}}.
\end{align}
$$