# Cauchy's Residue Theorem with Multiple Gamma Functions

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I previously posted a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078664/residue-theorem-for-gamma-function) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082295/integration-of-gamma-function). This time however I am dealing with multiple gamma functions. This is the problem I am dealing with right now:

$$
\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty}
\left(\,x^{-1}\sigma\,\right)^{s}\,
{\Gamma\left(s\right) \over \Gamma\left(s + 2\right)}\,{\rm d}s
$$

where β, σ and x are real number

I know that Cauchy's residue theorem is applicable for the evaluation but I cant figure out how can the simplification be made

Comment: See my [answer](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic45.html) under the use name mathematics.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal but my problem doesn't follow the same pattern in [your answer](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic45.html)

Comment: Try to work my problem (where I calculated the complex integral) in details to see what's going on then start to tackle your problems.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal you mentioned about poles at $\Gamma(a+iz)$. How about $\Gamma(a-iz)$?

Comment: @FelixMarin could you kindly help please?

Comment: @Ron Gordon already have a nice answer. Sorry I didn't read your comment before. Maybe I was sleeping or close to. I see you modified your question because the original one had two integrals. Next time. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin No Problem. I made the other integral a question on its own. Struggling with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083596/evaluate-integral-int-c-j-inftyc-j-infty-left-sigma-x-1-r), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083405/cauchys-residue-theorem-for-integral-int-c-j-inftyc-j-infty-lef) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083360/evaluate-complex-integral-with-term-gamma-lefts-over-2-right-gamma-left). Kindly help if you could. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral is relatively simple because it is simply

$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{s (s+1)}$$

where $t=\log{\left ( x^{-1} \sigma \right )}$.  This is a well-known inverse Laplace transform and may be evaluated using a Bromwich contour closed to the left or right according to the sign of $t$.  When $t \gt 0$, the integral is simply $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles (assuming $c \gt 0$, which I am); when $t \lt 0$, the integral is simply zero.  Thus, the integral is

$$i 2 \pi \left (1-e^{-t} \right ) \theta(t) = i 2 \pi \left (1-\frac{x}{\sigma} \right ) \theta(\sigma-x)$$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: may I know how ${\Gamma\left(\,s\,\right) \over \Gamma\left(\,s + 2\,\right)}$ becomes ${1 \over s(s+1)}$?

Comment: Definition of the Gamma function: $$\Gamma(x+1)=x \Gamma(x)$$

Comment: oh yes, thanks!