# Cauchy's Residue Theorem for Integral $\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty} \left({\sigma \over x}\right)^s{{1-\beta^{s+1}}\over s(s+1)}\,ds$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

This is a similar problem to the one I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083202/cauchys-residue-theorem-with-multiple-gamma-functions?noredirect=1#comment2207473_1083202). I am at this point of integration where:

$$\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty} \left({\sigma \over x}\right)^s{{1-\beta^{s+1}}\over s(s+1)}\,ds$$

whereby $\beta > 0$, $\sigma > 0$, $c>0$ and $|x|<\beta$. $\beta$, $\sigma$, $c$ and $x$ are all real numbers

Comment: Seems you are computing integrals of the type:

$$\displaystyle \int\limits_{c- j\infty}^{c+j\infty} \frac{x^{s}}{s(s+1)}\,ds = \begin{cases} \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) & \textrm { if } x \ge 1 \\ 0 & \textrm{ if } 1 \ge x \ge 0 \end{cases}$$

This is a particular case of the Mellin-Perron Integral see [here, page 24](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~mriedel/papers/markoriedelthesis.ps.gz) for example.

Comment: @r9m thank you, I'll try!

Comment: @r9m i can't open the file. may i know what file is that please? thanks

Comment: If you are on Linux, the tool ps2pdf converts that file to a PDF document. If you are on another OS, try googling for online converters.

Comment: @andrepd thank you :)

Comment: @r9m i have no issue if the integrand is $\frac{x^{s}}{s(s+1)}$. I am not so sure how to continue with integrand $\left({\sigma \over x}\right)^s{{1-\beta^{s+1}}\over s(s+1)}$ where $1-\beta^{s+1}$ is the multiplier

Comment: You should specify the signs of $\sigma\,,\ x$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @r9m If $x <0$, the OP must give a branch cut for $x^{s}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin $\sigma > 0$, $\beta > 0$ and $|x| < \beta$. I will add this into the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}
    {1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s\pars{s + 1}}\,\dd s:\ {\large ?}.\qquad
    \sigma > 0\,,\quad  \beta > 0\,,\quad x \in {\mathbb R}\,,\quad
    \verts{x} < \beta\,;\quad c > 0}$.

---

> First, we split the integral in two *similar* integrals:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}
{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s\pars{s + 1}}\,\dd s}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}
{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s}\,\dd s
-\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}
{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s + 1}\,\dd s
\\[5mm]&=\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}
\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s}\,\dd s
-{x \over \sigma}\int_{c\ +\ 1\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ 1\ +\ \infty\ic}
\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}{1 - \beta^{s} \over s}\,\dd s\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Because the singularity is at $\ds{s = 0}$, the second second integral can be evaluated from $\ds{c - \infty\ic}$ to $\ds{c + \infty\ic}$ such that
>   $\pars{1}$ is reduced to:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}
{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s\pars{s + 1}}\,\dd s}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}
\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s}\,\dd s
-{x \over \sigma}\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}
\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}{1 - \beta^{s} \over s}\,\dd s
\\[5mm]&=\pars{1 - {x \over \sigma}}\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}
\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}{1 \over s}\,\dd s
-\pars{\beta - {x \over \sigma}}
\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}
\pars{\sigma\beta \over x}^{s}{1 \over s}\,\dd s
\\[5mm]&=\pars{1 - {x \over \sigma}}\fermi\pars{\sigma \over x}
-\pars{\beta - {x \over \sigma}}\fermi\pars{\sigma\beta \over x}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> where
>   $\ds{\quad\fermi\pars{\mu}\equiv
>      \int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}{\mu^{s} \over s}\,\dd s\quad}$ with
>   $\ds{\quad\mu \not= 0.\quad}$ There a few cases we have to consider given the sign and magnitude of $\ds{\mu}$.

1. $\ds{\large\mu\ <\ 0}$

   We don't really know how the OP handles this case: Some definition should be established for $\ds{\mu^{s}}$. However, lets
   $\ds{\mu = \verts{\mu}\exp\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\ic\pi}}$ with
   $\ds{n \in {\mathbb Z}}$. $\ds{\mu^{s}}$ becomes
   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}~s = c + \ic y\,,\ y\ \in {\mathbb R}}}$
   $$
   \mu^{s}=\verts{\mu}^{c + \ic y}\exp\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\ic\pi c}
   \exp\pars{-\bracks{2n + 1}\pi y}
   $$
   such that
   $$
   \left.\fermi\pars{\mu}\right\vert_{\mu\ <\ 0}
   =\ic\exp\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\ic\pi c}\verts{\mu}^{c}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
   {\verts{\mu}^{\ic y} \exp\pars{-\bracks{2n + 1}\pi y} \over c + \ic y}\,\dd y
   $$
   We can see that, for any value of $\ds{n \in {\mathbb Z}}$, the integral diverges.
2. $\ds{\large 0\ <\ \mu\ <\ 1}$

   In this case we can write $\ds{\mu^{s} = \expo{-ts}}$ with $\ds{t > 0}$. By 'closing' the contour to the 'right' of the complex plane we conclude that
   $$\left.\fermi\pars{\mu}\right\vert_{0\ <\ \mu\ <\ 1} = 0$$.
3. $\ds{\large\mu\ =\ 1}$

   The integral diverges because
   $$
   \fermi\pars{1}=\int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}{\dd s \over s}
   =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ic\,\dd y \over c + \ic y}
   $$
   Note that
   \begin{align}
   \left.\int_{-a}^{b}{\ic\,\dd y \over c + \ic y}\right\vert_{a\ >\ 0\,,\ b\ >\ 0}&=
   \int_{-a}^{b}{y + \ic c \over y^{2} + c^{2}}\,\dd y
   \\[5mm]&=\half\,\ln\pars{b^{2} + c^{2} \over a^{2} + c^{2}}
   +\bracks{\arctan\pars{b \over c} + \arctan\pars{a \over c}}\ic
   \end{align}
4. $\ds{\large \mu > 1}$

   In this case we can write $\ds{\mu^{s} = \expo{ts}}$ with $\ds{t > 0}$. By 'closing' the contour to the 'left' of the complex plane we conclude that
   $$\left.\fermi\pars{\mu}\right\vert_{\mu\ >\ 1} = 2\pi\ic$$.

> In conclussion,

$$
\mbox{with}\quad \mu \in \pars{0,\infty} \verb*\* \braces{1}\,,\quad
\fermi\pars{\mu}=\left\{\begin{array}{lcrcccl}
0 & \mbox{if} & 0 & < & \mu & < & 1
\\[2mm]
2\pi\ic & \mbox{if} &&& \mu & > & 1
\end{array}\right.
$$

> Finally $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \pars{2}~}}$,

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{c\ -\ \infty\ic}^{c\ +\ \infty\ic}\pars{\sigma \over x}^{s}
{1 - \beta^{s + 1} \over s\pars{s + 1}}\,\dd s}
\\[5mm]&=\left\{\begin{array}{lcrcl}
0 & \mbox{if}\quad & 0 < {\sigma \over x} < 1\ & \mbox{and} &
0 < {\sigma\beta \over x} < 1 
\\[3mm]
2\pi\ic\pars{{x \over \sigma} - \beta}
& \mbox{if}\quad & 0 < {\sigma \over x} < 1 & \mbox{and} &
{\sigma\beta \over x} > 1 
\\[3mm]
2\pi\ic\pars{1 - {x \over \sigma}}
& \mbox{if}\quad & {\sigma \over x} > 1 & \mbox{and} &
0 < {\sigma\beta \over x} < 1 
\\[3mm]
2\pi\ic\pars{1 - \beta}
& \mbox{if}\quad & {\sigma \over x} > 1 & \mbox{and} &
{\sigma\beta \over x} > 1 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

Comment: how did ${1-\beta^{s+1}}\over{s}$ become $({1-{x \over \sigma}})({1 \over s})$ in the first integral? I assume the same procedure is followed in the second @FelixMarin

Comment: and did u assume $x>0$? Or is it an error in your first line of answer? Because $\beta>0$ and $x$ can be both positive and negative @FelixMarin

Comment: and since $x$ can be negative, the statement '$\ds{\mu > 0}$' is incorrect right? @FelixMarin

Comment: @arvindrajan92 I'll check tomorrow because right now it's too late.

Comment: sure @FelixMarin

Comment: @arvindrajan92 I checked the whole answer. Right now, I hope everything is quite clear.

Comment: thanks @FelixMarin. If u do find time, help me with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083360/evaluate-complex-integral-with-term-gamma-lefts-over-2-right-gamma-left) one also please. thanks and I'll take this from here