# Evaluate Integral $\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty} \left({\sigma\,x^{-1}}\right)^s{\Gamma(\beta_1-1+s)\over \Gamma(\beta_1+\beta_2-1+s)}\,ds$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I am at this point of integration where:

$$\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty} \left({\sigma\,x^{-1}}\right)^s{\Gamma(\beta_1-1+s)\over \Gamma(\beta_1+\beta_2-1+s)}\,ds$$

whereby $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\sigma$ and $x$ are real and $c>0$

Cauchy's residue theorem is used and I am not sure how the integral can be simplified to apply the theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** detect the poles of the integrand function with their residues, then move the integration line towards the left. Prove that, assuming $\beta_2>0$, the integral over a segment parallel to the real line vanishes as the distance from the real line goes to $+\infty$, then apply the residue theorem over a rectangular contour. See also [Mellin's transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform).

Comment: i'll try. need some help with [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083405/cauchys-residue-theorem-for-integral-int-c-j-inftyc-j-infty-lef) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083360/evaluate-complex-integral-with-term-gamma-lefts-over-2-right-gamma-left) if possible please. thanks

Comment: @arvindrajan92: the technique is just the same sketched here.

Comment: @JackDAurizio im now at $\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty} {e}^{ut}{\Gamma(u)\over \Gamma(u+\beta_2)}\,du$ and not sure how to move on

Comment: @arvindrajan92:  $e^{ut}$ is an entire function, $\frac{\Gamma(u)}{\Gamma(u+\beta_2)}$ a meromorphic one. Since $\Gamma\neq 0$, where are the poles of their product? What are the residues?

Comment: @JackDAurizio therefore the poles would be at $0,-1,-2,-3,...,-\inf$. I know those are the poles. But now i cant find the residue

Comment: @arvindrajan92: since they are simple poles, the residue of $e^{ut}\frac{\Gamma(u)}{\Gamma(u+\beta_2)}$ at $u=-n$ is just the residue of $\Gamma(u)$ at $u=-n$ times $\frac{1}{e^{nt}\Gamma(\beta_2-n)}$.

Comment: @JackDAurizio and that gives me $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta_2-n)}\frac{(-e^{-t})^n}{n!}$. Can this be simplified further?

Comment: @arvindrajan92: such expression gives a Bessel function.

Comment: okay thanks @JackDAurizio