# Simplify Infinite Series Involving Gamma Function $\Gamma$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, special-functions, gamma-function

This question originated from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083596/evaluate-integral-int-c-j-inftyc-j-infty-left-sigma-x-1-r/1083618#comment2207803_1083618) problem. Can anyone help me simplifying the infinite series below:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta_2-n)}\frac{(-e^{-t})^n}{n!}$$

The only idea I have is $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-e^{-t})^n}{n!}=e^{-e^{-t}}$ and I am not sure what to do with $\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta_2-n)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first simplify the expression by writing $x=-e^{-t}$ and $\beta_2=a+1$. Then we are left

with evaluating $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!~(a-n)!}$ , which, after employing [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for

the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), in conjunction with that of the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), becomes $-(1+x)^a~\cdot~\Gamma(-a)~\cdot$

$\cdot~\dfrac{\sin a\pi}\pi$.